# Standardize date string for datetime string

Tags: java, regex

Please, could you help me with this problem? I have tried to implement the below solutions, but both weren't working.

Problem:

I have to standardize all string dates in the CSV file to YYYY-MM-DD HH: MM: SS:

```
2021-01-03 12:15:33.12365478 -> 2021-01-03 12:15:33 
2021-01-03 -> 2021-01-03 00:00:00
```

Input file:

```
OP|VALUE1|VALUE2|DATE
I |123   | ABC  | 2021-01-03 12:15:33.12365478
I |123   | ABC  | 2021-01-03 12:15:21
I |123   | ABC  | 2021-01-03 12:15:12
I |123   | ABC  | 2021-01-03
I |123   | ABC  | 2021-01-03 12:15:33.12365478
```

Wish output file:

```
OP|VALUE1|VALUE2|DATE
I |123   | ABC  | 2021-01-03 12:15:33
I |123   | ABC  | 2021-01-03 12:15:21
I |123   | ABC  | 2021-01-03 12:15:12
I |123   | ABC  | 2021-01-03 00:00:00
I |123   | ABC  | 2021-01-03 12:15:33
```

Each file size is around 104MB.
The solutions that I thought:

Alternative 1:

```
 public static String setDataCleaner(String in) {
        String stringFinal = "";
        
        for(String i: in.split("\\|")){
            
            if(i.matches("[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}")) {
                stringFinal += i+" 00:00:00|";
            }else if(i.matches("[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}.\\d+")) {
                stringFinal += i.substring(0,19)+"|";
            }else {
                stringFinal += i+"|";
            }
        }
        return(stringFinal);
    }
```

This first alternative is slow because the 104MB are split by "|" and then, each part of this split is checked against regex, one by one!

The second alternative was:

```
public static String setDataCleaner(String in) {
    Pattern pattData1 = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}.\\d+");
    Pattern pattData2 = Pattern.compile("\\|[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\\|");

    String newString = "";
    Matcher matcher = pattData1.matcher(in);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        newString = in.substring(0, matcher.start()) + matcher.group().substring(0, 19)
                + in.substring(matcher.end());
    }

    matcher = pattData2.matcher(newString);
    String temp = "";

    while (matcher.find()) {
        temp = newString.substring(0, matcher.start());
        temp += matcher.group().substring(1, 11) + " 00:00:00|";
        temp += newString.substring(matcher.end());

    }
    return temp;
}
```

The second alternative looks better but, the temp variable is overridden each occurrence of my regex match, and, as the first attempt, it is slow too!

So, I can't found a simple alternative where i could, for example, carry out an replaAll() and, in the same time, use the part of the match valeu, like this:

```
String temp = "I|123|abc|2021-01-03 12:15:33.151615645"
tmp.replaceAll("<regexDateFormatt>", initialFoundDate+" 00:00:00")
```

or

```
String temp = "I|123|abc|2021-01-03 12:15:33"
tmp.replaceAll("<regexDateFormatt>", initialFoundDate.substring(0,19))
```

Comment: Take a look at this [tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/parsing-formatting-dates.html) to parse and format dates.

Comment: If len = 10, append `" 00:00:00"`. Truncate to max len of 19. All done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replaceAll` on each line twice (without using `split`):

```
String res = line.replaceAll("(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}).*$", "$1")
                 //remove everything after seconds
                 .replaceAll("(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})$", "$1 00:00:00");
                 //add 00:00:00 if time is not present
```

The final version to handle the format below:

```
I|2083|11111|false|1.53|2021-05-26 07:42:26.1263748559|2021-05-26.1263748559 
I|2030|22222|false|2.00|2021-05-26|2021-05-26


public static String setDataCleaner(String entrada) {
    return (entrada.replaceAll("((\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})\\.\\d*)", "$2")
                .replaceAll("\\|([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})([\\|])", "|$1 00:00:00|")
                .replaceAll("\\|([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})\r", "|$1 00:00:00"));
}
```

Comment: Hi @iota! We are almost there!  My fault doesn't put a real and complete scenario of my case. It is exactly what I need but, due to my previous examples, some regex not match!  could you help thinking about it?. I need to match the following scenario: I|2083|11111|false|1.53|2021-05-26 07:42:26.1263748559|2021-05-26.1263748559
I|2030|22222|false|2.00|2021-05-26|2021-05-26. As you can observe, I have milliseconds and incomplete dates between " | " and in the and of my string!

Answer (score 1):

I love regular expressions, but here's another perspective which I think is simpler.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws ParseException {
    List<String> dates = List.of("2021-01-03 12:15:33.12365478", 
        "2021-01-03 12:15:21",
        "2021-01-03 12:15:12",
        "2021-01-03",
        "2021-01-03 12:15:33.12365478");
    
    for (String dateStr : dates) {
      SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
      dateFormat.setLenient(false);
      Date date = null;
      try {
        date = dateFormat.parse(dateStr);
      } catch (ParseException pe) {
        System.err.println("Wrong format: " + dateStr);
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        date = df.parse(dateStr);
      }
      System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
    }
}
```

The basic assumption is that most of your dates comply with a common format of `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` and thus will pass a straight conversion. The failing cases will be those without the time component and you can handle those as an exceptional case.

In the end, both cases (regular and exceptional) will be validated and converted to the desired date format string.

This is the output of my program:

```
2021-01-03 12:15:33
2021-01-03 12:15:21
2021-01-03 12:15:12
Wrong format: 2021-01-03
2021-01-03 00:00:00
2021-01-03 12:15:33
```

For developers who aren't necessarily well-versed in regular expressions, this solution is more readable and because of that, will be much easier to maintain. Readability of code is something that should not be overlooked when making these kind of decisions.

Comment: Hi @hfontanez thanks! So, I guess that I need a less complex scenario. Your answer and thought are incredible, congratulations! But, in my case, beyond I found the wrong pattern I need to replace it with the same pattern but with some fewer characters OR increase them! I tested string.replaceAll() and looks fine but i1m stuck in regex because I have the following pattern: I|2083|11111|false|1.53|2021-05-26 07:42:26.1263748559|2021-05-26.1263748559 I|2030|22222|false|2.00|2021-05-26|2021-05-26 As you can observe, I have milliseconds and incomplete dates between " | " and in the and of my line!

Comment: @FelipeCabral break down the larger problem into smaller problems. In your case, it might be better off in breaking off per line. Then figure out the date columns. If the dates are always in the same column, then you can simply extract the column (maybe by splitting again by "|" and using array index to get the date String. Lastly, pass this to a function to convert the date. That's where you could use my method. The proposed REGEX solution might be better, but might not be readable which is a problem.